# Access: how to transfer value from calculated query(table1) to table2?

Tags: ms-access

I'm new with Access, I'M sure this can be done, (in excel it can) just can't figure it out on Access after 1 week of searching the web, please help.

What I'm trying to achieve is transfer the result of a calculated query to another table for statistics purposes.

I have a table called 'Database' which records data on people( Date in, Date out, age, etc).

I have a query called 'New Arrivals' which calculates how many people arrived today. Let assume my answer is 4.

I want to transfer the value '4' to another table called 'Statistics' in the field called New Arrivals. My goal is to be able to lookup my statistics for any given day.

How do I do this?

Regards,

JF

Comment: Why? A query should be able to accomplish that statistical summary whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

SQL

INSERT INTO target [(field1[, field2[, …]])]
VALUES (value1[, value2[, …]])

Add records to a table by using an append query
https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/add-records-to-a-table-by-using-an-append-query-98a5bd66-2190-4243-9638-8ef649cf3596